# JAVA url = new URL () malformedURLexception

Tags: java, url, malformedurlexception

I was trying to build a crawler that collects HTML sourcecodes from websites, which I have in a .csv file. 
Everything seems to be working fine whenever I place the link in

```
url = new URL ("http://example.com")
```

but whenever I try to place the link in a variable ("text" in this example) I get an error, telling me that there has been a malformedURLException.

Here is my code:

```
String text ="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827143/continuing-execution-after-an-exception-is-thrown-in-java";

// get the sourcecode of the link you just grabbed
url = new URL(text);
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("sourcecode.txt", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: There seems to be a hidden space in your `String text ="[hidden space or character here"]htt....` that could very well be the source of your malformed URL. It appeared when I copied your code into another editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have hidden characters in your string. You probably copied the URL from a Word file or a text file that was converted in Windows. There is a BOM marker in its beginning. When I do this:

```
System.out.println( Arrays.toString(text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE)));
```

This is the output I get:

```
[-2, -1, 0, 104, 0, 116, 0, 116, 0, 112, 0, 58, 0, 47, 0, 47, 0, 115, 0, 116, 0, 97, 0, 99, 0, 107, 0, 111, 0, 118, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 102, 0, 108, 0, 111, 0, 119, 0, 46, 0, 99, 0, 111, 0, 109, 0, 47, 0, 113, 0, 117, 0, 101, 0, 115, 0, 116, 0, 105, 0, 111, 0, 110, 0, 115, 0, 47, 0, 57, 0, 56, 0, 50, 0, 55, 0, 49, 0, 52, 0, 51, 0, 47, 0, 99, 0, 111, 0, 110, 0, 116, 0, 105, 0, 110, 0, 117, 0, 105, 0, 110, 0, 103, 0, 45, 0, 101, 0, 120, 0, 101, 0, 99, 0, 117, 0, 116, 0, 105, 0, 111, 0, 110, 0, 45, 0, 97, 0, 102, 0, 116, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 45, 0, 97, 0, 110, 0, 45, 0, 101, 0, 120, 0, 99, 0, 101, 0, 112, 0, 116, 0, 105, 0, 111, 0, 110, 0, 45, 0, 105, 0, 115, 0, 45, 0, 116, 0, 104, 0, 114, 0, 111, 0, 119, 0, 110, 0, 45, 0, 105, 0, 110, 0, 45, 0, 106, 0, 97, 0, 118, 0, 97]
```

The first two bytes are the unicode BOM character. Be careful where you get your strings from. If you export your CSV from Excel, and the file contains only URLs, try to export it as ASCII only.

Comment: Thank you! That was it, I suggested that there seems to be some weird char in it, but I couldn't figure out where, and where it originated from.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your double quote.

I pasted your "text" line into Eclipse and tried to save, and it showed me that there was an invalid character at the start of your "text" string because there was a Cp1252 encoded character.

I deleted the first double quote you had, and retyped it. Then I ran

```
String text = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827143/continuing-execution-after-an-exception-is-thrown-in-java";

try {
    URL url = new URL(text);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("sourcecode.txt", "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("all good");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have a special char in your text variable. Just tried your link in a Browser and it did not work because of this.

Copy the following and try again:

```
​String text ="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827143/continuing-execution-after-an-exception-is-thrown-in-java";
```